# Run Sublime Text and open a file within an Openedge app

Tags: sublimetext, openedge, progress-4gl

Is there a way to launch Sublime Text (v4) within Openedge to open a file or send data from Openedge to Sublime and attach triggers to it so that if the user saves the file in Sublime or closes Sublime, it also does something in Openedge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching Sublime Text from ABL should not be too hard. Look at the `OS-COMMAND` statement. You will need to read the Sublime documentation to see how to pass on a file name to open.

As for events in Sublime, that's also part of the Sublime doc. You may end up having to write a plugin that can communicate back to your application (via sockets or some other inter-process mechanism).